# How to trigger a method from a route you are directing to?

Tags: flutter

So I have a map view where I route to another view. In that map route I got a method:

```dart
  void animateToUser() async {
    final pos = await _location.getLocation();
    _mapController?.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(pos.latitude!, pos.longitude!), zoom: 15)));
  }
```

When Im on another view I use this to go back to the screen

```dart
  onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
   })
```

However I would like to trigger this `animateToUser` method just after the pop method. Is this achievable?

Comment: when pushing your new route do `Navigator.push(...).then((_) {call whatever you want here})` - you dont need any additional callbacks at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass this callback to your new screen. so you have access to call it before `Navigator.of(context).pop();`.

Comment: How do I pass it as callback? I am using this: `Naviagator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>AnotherView()));`

Comment: `Naviagator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>AnotherView(callback: () {your code})));` also you have to add callback to the constructor of AnotherView

Comment: It will be `callback: animateTouser()`? and then in constructor of AnotherView I add ({required Function callback})?

Comment: also Im getting this error `This expression has type 'void' and can't be used `AnotherView(callback: animateToUser());`

Comment: callback: animateTouser‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍ in fact. without parenthesize.

Comment: that's right. try checking your animateToUser function.